# How to draw two graphs overlaid on each other with plotly?

Tags: python, 3d, plotly, data-visualization, plotly-python

I'd like to now show several of the graphs in plotly overlaid on each other using `plotly.graph_objects`.  It's not clear how to accomplish that using the plotly API.

Background: I'm using plotly to show 3D data.  This is working quite well, and the ability to move around in 3D in really valuable to be able to undestand the data.  To show each graph by itself, I use calls like this:

```
    import plotly.graph_objects as go
    fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scatter3d(...))
    fig.show()
```

and

```
    fig = go.Figure(data=go.Volume(...))
    fig.show()
```

Each new figure displays separately; each figure apparently takes just one data=... in its constructor.  How do I make two different things show up in the *same* figure?  I want them to share everything (axes etc); the later ones can occlude the earlier ones if they happen to overlap.  How can new things to display be added to the same `go.Figure()` after it's constructed?

Comment: Have you looked at using traces? `fig.add_trace` should allow you to overlay data on the same figure.

Comment: @DerekO That worked - you can post it as an answer if you'd like so I can accept it:)

Comment: Sure will do. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To overlay data in the same figure, you can use `fig.add_trace`, adding as many traces as you need:

```
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter3d(data=...))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter3d(data=...))
...

fig.show()
```